# ODBC Error Connecting Teradata

Tags: linux, odbc, teradata, symbols

I have installed Teradata ODBC driver on Debian via alien.

Dependencies checked via ldd and are fufiled..

But when attempting to connect to the DB I am getting following errors (with Debug)

```
  user@server:/#isql -v testdsn username password
  4647:     find library=libodbc.so.1 [0]; searching
  4647:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
  4647:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.1
  4647:
  *** output omitted ***
  4647:
  4647:
  4647:     initialize program: isql
  4647:
  4647:
  4647:     transferring control: isql
  4647:
  4647:     find library=libnss_compat.so.2 [0]; searching
  4647:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
  4647:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat.so.2
  4647:
  *** output omitted ***
  4647:     calling init: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO8859-1.so
  4647:
  4647:     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO8859-1.so: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: gconv_end (fatal)
  4647:     find library=libstdc++.so.6 [0]; searching
  4647:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
  4647:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
  *** output omitted ***
  4647:     calling init: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so
  4647:
  4647:
  4647:     calling init: /opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/lib/tdata.so
  4647:
  4647:     /opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/lib/tdata.so: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: tdata_LTX_SQLDriverLoad (fatal)
  4647:     /opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/lib/tdata.so: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: SQLDriverLoad (fatal)
  4647:     /opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/lib/tdata.so: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: tdata_LTX_SQLDriverUnload (fatal)
  4647:     /opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/lib/tdata.so: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: SQLDriverUnload (fatal)
  4647:     /opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/lib/tdata.so: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: tdata_LTX_SQLAllocConnect (fatal)
  4647:     /opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/lib/tdata.so: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: SQLAllocConnect (fatal)
  4647:     /opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/lib/tdata.so: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: tdata_LTX_SQLAllocEnv (fatal)
  4647:     /opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/lib/tdata.so: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: SQLAllocEnv (fatal)
  *** output omitted ***
```

Any idea how to get rid of those errors? It seems to be a root cause of failing connections

Architecture X64

OS Debian 7

Driver version 16.00

same behaviour

OS CentOS 7

Driver version 16.00

Driver version 15.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly found it,
Terradata ODBC driver is incompatible with unixODBC Driver Manager. Odbc Driver Manager supplied with teradata **have** to be used.

It is stated in documentation that its shiped with specific Driver Manager but there is no mention that its strictly **INCOMPATIBLE** with anything else